# Power Shell , How to Suppress parameters errors and still use parameters?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PowerShell script that receive a named parameter.

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 0)][DateTime]$from 
)
```

I want to suppress parameter validation errors as well

For example:

*MyScript.ps1 "12/12/2023" aaaa will fail*

```
 A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
argument 'aaa'.
```

I figured out that if I defined the code in that order:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "silentlyContinue"
param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 0)][DateTime]$from 
)
```

then I'll not get the failures on the parameters, but the parameter $from is empty or null.

If I run the same code in the opposite order, the parameter will be filled bit will fail on the validation errors.

```
param(
         [Parameter(Mandatory=$false, Position = 0)][DateTime]$from 
    )
 $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlyContinue"
```

**How can I use the parameters and suppress the errors?**

Comment: Why are you typing the `$from` parameter as `[datetime]` if you want to accept non-`[datetime]` arguments?

Comment: Dito to the above, but also, if your script takes only one parameter, then why send it **two** when calling it: `MyScript.ps1 "12/12/2023" aaaa`

Comment: regular use should be with one parameter, date time, but I need to check use cases of users that enter invalid number pf parameters etc

Comment: Add a new parameter that enables `ValueFromRemainingArguments` and then check if that parameter was bounded

Answer (score 1):

If a second unexpected parameter could be passed, what you could do is stop using Param() and alternatively use $args array.

```
function test-parameters
{
   try {
       Get-Date $args[0] -Format "MM/yyyy"
   }
   catch {
       $Error[0].Exception.Message
   }
   $from = $args[0]
}
```

The `PS C:\>test-parameters "12/12/2023 aaa` is

```
12/2023
```

Comment: those are parameters for power shell script, not to function. In my case it failed on the first line of the script, a.k.a the param definition

Comment: @R.P, if you set a Param block, any script or function will ignore the $Args array. If you want to use it, delete the Param() block.

$Args works for scripts and functions.

Answer (score 1):

While dkabal’s answer works, you can actually get the best of both worlds - named parameters and a "handle the rest" parameter that will allow you to pass a variable number of values:

```
function Testy {
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$True,
            Position = 0
        )]
        [string]
        $firstArg,
     
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$True,
            ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true,
            Position = 1
        )][string[]]
        $listArgs
    )
    '$firstArg: {0}' -f $firstArg
    $count = 0
    foreach($listArg in $listArgs) {
        '$listArgs[{0}]: {1}' -f $count, $listArg
        $count++
    }
}

Testy one two three four
```

The key is to ‘decorate’ the parameter with `ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true` and specify that its position is always *after* the named parameters. Remember that the positions for arguments are always 0-origin, so if you have three named parameters plus a catch-all, you'd specify `$catchall` as having position 3.